# Laravel testing with phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, phpunit

How can I make sure that when I'm testing in Laravel with phpunit and for example I want to test my api route `/test/1` it uses my test database?

I already made a test connection and changed my phpunit.xml file. I changed `DB_CONNECTION` to the test connection that I made.

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing"/>
```

But it when I make a post request I receive data from the development database?

Comment: Have you also setup the array of config values in config/database.php?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Config/database.php` file, what is the value of database in `mysql_testing`? It should be like this:

```
'mysql_testing' => [ 
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('TEST_DB_DATABASE', 'db_testing'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

And database `db_testing` must exists.

Answer (score 0):

Inside one of your test files, add the following to output your current `DB_CONNECTION`:

`dd(env('DB_CONNECTION'));`

You should get `mysql_testing` in your test output if PHPUnit.xml is properly setup.